# Kafka Console Consumer : Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-kafka

I turn off one of the nodes in Kafka(cluster with 3 nodes) now When I consume other nodes, I encounter this message?

```
[2018-04-20 22:03:47,053] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-36123] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: Could you add your consumer configuration? If `bootstrap.servers` contains one node only and that is the node you turned off, consumer will not connect to the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons this could happen, but you're getting `node -1`, so a connection was not established to the broker (as the error says, it is not available). You should first describe the topic so that you can see what partitions and broker ids *are available*.

For example, If your topic had less than 2 replicas such that it is not be available on each broker, then you would see similar exceptions.

If you want to guarantee highly available topics, then you need to ensure that replication factors are at least 2 or 3, then `min.insync.replicas` is higher than 1 as well, plus `acks=all` in a Producer would ensure the data is being replicated for each batch sent. And then, your consumers would have a lower chance of seeing that message.